# Divide area into N convex fields efficiently

Tags: matlab, performance

I am trying to generate a set of points, where groups of m points are evenly distributed over a large area. I have solved the problem (solution below), but I am looking for a more elegant or at least faster solution.

Say we have 9 points we want to place in groups of 3 in an area specified by `x=[0,5]` and `y=[0,5]`. Then I first generate a mesh in this area

```
meshx = 0:0.01:5;
meshy = 0:0.01:5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(meshx,meshy);
X = X(:); Y = Y(:);
```

Then to place the 9/3=3 groups evenly I apply `kmeans` clustering

```
idx = kmeans([X,Y],3);
```

Then for each cluster, I can now draw a random sample of 3 points, which I save to a list:

```
pos = zeros(9,2);
for i = 1:max(idx)
    spaceX = X(idx==i);
    spaceY = Y(idx==i);
    %on = convhulln([spaceX,spaceY]);
    %plot(spaceX(on),spaceY(on),'black')
    %hold on
    sample = datasample([spaceX,spaceY],3,1);
    %plot(sample(:,1),sample(:,2),'black*')
    %hold on
    pos((i-1)*3+1:i*3,:) = sample;
end
```

If you uncomment the comments, then the code will also plot the clusters and the location of points within. My problem is as mentioned to primarily avoid having to cluster a rather fine uniform grid to make the code more efficient.

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox you can generate `m` random points and use the second output of [bwdist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) to partition the space.

Comment: Would you like to give an example?

Comment: The result of kmeans is no deterministic. You may get different results based on the starting random configuration of the centers. Do you want polygons with nearly equal areas?Or do you want polygons with different areas ? Should they placed randomly or they should be regularly spaced.

Comment: I want polygons with nearly equal areas. The keyword is "evenly", they should be evenly spaced, whether this is random or not, does not matter. I am really just after reproducing the result that I get with `kmean`, but faster, as I believe that there must be some way to know the outcome, when the data is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `kmeans` you can use `atan2` :

```
x= -10:10;
idx=ceil((bsxfun(@atan2,x,x.')+pi)*(3/(2*pi)));
imshow(idx,[])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however this only works for 1-4 areas, from 5 and onward the division no longer behaves as "cake slicing". E.g. try to change the 3 in `kmeans` to 5.

Comment: @NickyMattsson Please try `kmeans` with for `meshx =1:21`. The result is the same as of `atan2`. That is because the resolution of the grid is coarse.

Comment: It is not the coarseness of the grid which is the problem. As you apply `atan2` the result looks like how you would slice a cake with lines going from the edge to the centre. This is correct for 1-4 slices, but for 5, this is incorrect. This is what I should get: http://imgur.com/lD8rLW4

Comment: @NickyMattsson OK , I understand. However a cake slice is a convex  field.